# Using variable for selectors in events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

for some reason I need to use a variable as the selector for events in backbone, but I can't figure how to do this :

```
app.views.Selfcare = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        click window.parent.document .close : "closeWindow"
    },
    closeWindow: function() {
        //code
    }
});
```

I have to use a different scope and I can't do "click .close" : "closeWindow".

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a look at Backbone.js's source code and found out that if your view's `events` is a function then the function is called and it's return value is used as the `events` object.

This means that your code can be changed like this:

```
app.views.Selfcare = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: function() {
    var _events = {
      // all "standard" events can be here if you like
    }
    _events["events" + "with variables"] = "closeWindow";
    return _events;

  },
  closeWindow: function() {
    //code
  }
});
```

**[THIS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-118)** is the interesting part of the source code:

```
if (_.isFunction(events)) events = events.call(this);
```

**Update:**

Example is available on JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/rrjUU/)**

Comment: Nice. I'll try this in the next hours, and tell you. Thx a lot.

Comment: @Flyingbeaver I updated my answer with the link to a silly example. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you'll be able to use a variable there. You could use the built-in Events methods (see [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events)) to add a custom listener, then add an event listener to `window.parent.document` to trigger that custom event (use the [Events.trigger](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-trigger) method).

That said, it would be much easier to decouple this event from Backbone entirely (unless you don't want to do that), and go down the addEventListener route:

```
app.views.Selfcare = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'closeWindow');
        if(this.options.clickTarget) {
            this.options.clickTarget.addEventListener('click', this.closeWindow, false);
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        // Render to the DOM here
        return this; // as per Backbone conventions
    },
    closeWindow: function() {
        // Stuff here
    }
});

// Usage:
var mySelfcare = new app.views.Selfcare({
    clickTarget: window.parent.document
});
```

I think that should work, although I haven't tested it (and there may be one or two syntactical errors!)

Comment: Thx for the example, I was also thinking about taking out this event, however I could have a lot. Dzejkej solution seems very interesting.

Comment: @Flyingbeaver: Yep, just seen that solution too, v. elegant :)